# Upgrade from 15.10 to 16.04 - "no new release found"

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, 15.10

I have Ubuntu 15.10 installed. I want to upgrade to 16.04. The option to do this does not show up in software updater. When I ran `do-release-upgrade -cd` it returns `No new release found`.

So I downloaded the iso and put it on a usb stick. When I boot up into the installer the option to upgrade 15.10 to 16.04 is blanked out. It will allow me to erase the current installation or install alongside.

Is there anything else I can try before erasing my current installation (thus losing some of my settings).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change your software sources from wily to xenial, then update, upgrade and dist-upgrade.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, writing from a phone sometimes bug with autocorrect. Regards

Comment: how do i go about this?

Comment: 1. 'sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list'   2. Check every rows to find the word wily and change those to xenial     2. Ctrl-X to save, Y to yes, Press Enter key    3. Update, upgrade, dist-upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
exec sudo -i
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
nano /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
```

In the open file, leave this line as:

```
Prompt=lts
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> Save file

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> Close nano

Reboot your system to finish installing updates, and to upgrade to new available version:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
exec sudo -i
update-manager -d
```

Software Updater will show up and search for the new release, after a few seconds, you will see a screen like below that saying:

However, Ubuntu 16.04 is available now (you have 15.10).

Press the button Upgrade to start upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04.

The Software Updater will ask you to confirm still you want to upgrade, press Start Upgrade to begin installing Ubuntu 16.04.

Now, the Software Updater will prepare to start setting up new software channels, and after a few minutes, the software updater will notify you the details the number of packages are going to be removed, and number of packages are going to be installed, press Start upgrade to continue.

Ended the dist-upgrade, reboot your system and:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
exec sudo -i
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get -f install
apt-get -m install
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
```

Comment: when i did this the updater just told me that the software is up to date.